# LINQ and XML with C#

Tags: c#, linq

```
<root>
    <level1 name="A">
        <level2 name="A1" />
        <level2 name="A2" />
    </level1>
    <level1 name="B">
        <level2 name="B1" />
        <level2 name="B2" />
    </level1>
    <level1 name="C" />
</root>
```

Could someone give me a C# code using LINQ, the simplest way to print this result:
(Note the extra space if it is a level2 node)

```
A
  A1
  A2
B
  B1
  B2
C

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml"));
var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("level1")
           select lv1.Attribute("name").Value;

foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
{
    result.AppendLine(lv1);

    var lv2s = from lv2 in xdoc...???
}
```

Comment: -1 You completely changed your question, invalidating all the answers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var lookup = xDoc.Descendants("param")
                 .ToLookup(x => x.Attribute("name").Value, x => (double)x);

foreach (var p in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,6:#0.0} {2,6:#0.0} {3,6:#0.0}", 
                        p.Key,  p.Min(),  p.Average(),  p.Max());
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
temperature     9.3   10.3   11.2
pH              3.0    6.3   10.0
Phosphate       4.0    4.0    4.0
Chloride        4.0    4.0    4.0
Nitrate        10.0   10.0   10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

By using XPath, here's how you could do it for the average:

```
float GetAvgTemperature(XmlDocument document)
{
    var temperatureNodes = document.SelectNodes("/samples/measurement/param[@name='temperature']");
    return temperatureNodes == null ? 0 : temperatureNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().Average(node => float.Parse(node.InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

You can easily make this function more generic to return either Minimum/Average/Maximum and for any parameter name.

Comment: He's using `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`.

Comment: @CoryNelson Is it so much important? Only the method name changes `XPathSelectElements`

Comment: Didn't realize that, but I think that OP didn't specifically mention that the solution has to use `XDocument` and as EZI suggested, it doesn't make that much of a difference. The real difference with the other answers is that my solution uses the xPath engine which has its advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses the LINQ aggregation to build the calculations in a single line of code as you requested.

```
var values = samples.Descendants(XName.Get("param"))
    .Select(n => new {
        Name = n.Attribute(XName.Get("name")).Value,
        Value = float.Parse(n.Value)
    })
    .GroupBy(a => a.Name)
    .Select(a => new {
        Name = a.Key,
        MaxValue = a.Max(g => g.Value),
        MinValue = a.Min(g => g.Value),
        AvgValue = a.Average(g => g.Value)
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `Descendants("param")` unless you are validating the document in another way. Otherwise, if the document's format changes it might result in some unexpected results.

Here's what you want:

```
from p in samples.Elements("samples").Elements("measurement").Elements("param")
group (double)p by (string)p.Attribute("name") into grp
select new
{
    ParameterName = grp.Key,
    Min = grp.Min(),
    Avg = grp.Average(),
    Max = grp.Max()
}
```

Note the chained of `Elements()` calls, which makes precisely selecting down into the document very trivial, and casting of the `XAttribute` and `XElement` directly to `double` and `string` to get their values.